# Image to act as a button HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, button

Hello I have this code:

```
 <!-- Button that triggers the popup -->
            <button id="my-button">POP IT UP</button>
            <!-- Element to pop up -->
            <div id="element_to_pop_up">Content of popup</div>
```

And I have this image:

```
<img src="botones/bannerdiseno_audifonosinpilas.png" width="160" height="33"  alt=""/>
</a><a href="tecnologia.html">
```

I want to know how to change the link on that image to do the same the button does, whats the syntax that I should use, so whenever I click the image it'd trigger the button action and remove the button itself

Thanks

Comment: you can use the button and make it look like the image using css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <img onclick="document.getElementById('my-button').click()" src="botones/bannerdiseno_audifonosinpilas.png" width="160" height="33"  alt=""/>

or 

<a href="javascript: document.getElementById('my-button').click()"> <img src="botones/bannerdiseno_audifonosinpilas.png" width="160" height="33"  alt=""/></a>
```

Comment: And now, how do I actually hide or remove the button? since Im calling it using the "my-button"

Comment: document.getElementById('my-button').style.display='none';

or with jQuery $('#my-button').hide()

Comment: or you can just do <button style="display: none"/>

Answer (score 0):

You can use [input `type="image"`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_src.asp)

```
<input type="image" src="submit.gif" alt="Submit">
```